# prestashop generate a new form content with renderform via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, prestashop

I created a button when clicked triggers the renderForm function with prestashop that is supposed to generate the form via ajax.But it doesn't seem to work.
Can anyone please help me or point me in the right direction because i'm new with prestashop ?
in the catproduct.php

```
public function generateform(){

$html = '<a href="#" class="displayForm">Click me</a>
         <div id="myFormm"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $( ".displayForm" ).click(function() {
            $.ajax({
              url: "'._MODULE_DIR_.$this->name.'/ajax.php",
              context: document.body,
                })
                .done(function(data) {
                $( "#myFormm" ).html( data );
                alert( "Load was performed." );
            });


        })
    </script>';



return $html;

}


public function renderForm()
{
    $fields_form = array(
        'form' => array(
            'legend' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Add new category'),
                'icon' => 'icon-cogs'
            ),
            'input' => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('FCI'),
                    'name' => 'FCI',
            ),
            ),

            'submit' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Save')
            )
        ),
    );
    $helper = new HelperForm();
    $helper->show_toolbar = false;
    $helper->table = $this->table;
    $lang = new Language((int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'));
    $helper->default_form_language = $lang->id;
    $helper->allow_employee_form_lang = Configuration::get('PS_BO_ALLOW_EMPLOYEE_FORM_LANG') ? Configuration::get('PS_BO_ALLOW_EMPLOYEE_FORM_LANG') : 0;
    $this->fields_form = array();

    $helper->identifier = $this->identifier;
    $helper->submit_action = 'submitCatForm';
    $helper->fields_value['FCI'] = 'ddddd';
    $helper->currentIndex = $this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminModules', false).'&configure='.$this->name.'&tab_module='
    .$this->tab.'&module_name='.$this->name;
    $helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');

    return $helper->generateForm(array($fields_form));
}
```

the ajax.php file (the ajax file call the renderForm() function to create new form):

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'../../../config/config.inc.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'../../../init.php');

include_once('catproduct.php'); 
$module = new catproduct(); 
echo $module->renderForm();
```

Comment: Please include any code or errors so we can see what you have already done.

Comment: i include my code is there any solution ?